# How to use several shapes together as a mask in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, mask

I'm quite a noob when it comes to Sketch still, but I often use it for quick edits of images etc.

Now I want to create a customized mask for use in social profiles for my music. 
I want it to be a circle with triangles pointing to all 4 corners. But when I'm trying to mask, only one shape gets used. Even if I select all 5 of them. I tried exporting it as a png, but then I'm unable to use it as a mask.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the objects (four arrow shapes) into a group <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, then select the grouped objects and use the **Union** button or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in the toolbar to make them one shape:

***Step 1:*** *Group the separate Objects*
[image: Grouping objects]

***Step 2:*** *Selecting Objects and Select **Union** in Toolbar*
[image]

[image: Combined shape]
*-The combined shape*

***Step 3:*** *Drag the shape you want to mask above the newly combined shape*
[image: Drag mask below the shape you want to mask]

***Step 4:*** *Select **Mask** in the toolbar*
[image: Final mask]

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much mate. Been wasting a lot of time trying to figure this out, so it is very much appreciated. Let me know if I can tip you a few bucks of crypto somewhere =)

Comment: No problem...a simple upvote and accepted answer will do :)

Comment: Accepted as answer now, but don't have the reputation to give a public upvote =/ Thanks again though 